# IIS7 startup site

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have a Windows 2008 Server with IIS7 on it and a web page running under the name, let's say *myApplication*. I have a domain name that points to the IP of my server, let's say *myApplication.com*.

In order to access my application I have to enter *http://myApplication.com/myApplication*.
If I write http://myApplication.com/ I arrive to the IIS7 start page. Is there a way (besides rewriting the *iisstart.htm* to make a JavaScript or meta-data redirect) to automatically open the *myApplication* when someone enters "*http://myApplication.com/*"?

What I would like is the following:

- The user enters in the browser: "http://myApplication.com/"
- He/she is taken to "http://myApplication.com/myApplication"
- In the URL bar of the browser only "http://myApplication.com/" shows and everything inside the application is relative to this URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when I configure IIS, I set the properties for the "default web site" to a folder that doesn't contain anything, then create individual entries within IIS for each web site.  For example, you would create a new entry for "MyApplication.com" and set its home directory to the proper folder on the server that contains your root files (usually c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapplication.com\ but it could be anywhere you like).

It sounds as if you have created a folder for your application, but do not have a specific entry in IIS configured to handle the requests and load files from the proper folder.

If you have a dedicated IP address for the application, be sure to specify that IP within the site settings for that site.  If you're using a single IP for multiple sites, configure the IP AND hostnames/domains that will be used to access that site so IIS will know which site entries belong to which domains and where to route the requests.