# Redirect is not working properly in iis

Tags: .htaccess, iis, redirect

I have a problem similer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355402/iis7-startup-site)

I have tried this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myApplication.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !myApplication/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myApplication/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.myApplication.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !myApplication/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myApplication/$1 [L]
```

but the problem is url is working only with www.myApplication.com/myApplication but I want to hide myApplication subfolder .
I will really appreciate any help on this.

UPDATE:
I have tried this which is giving 500 server error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="mod_rewrite" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="path to scriptproc" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" preCondition="bitness32" />
        </handlers>
        <rule name="Rewrite to myApplicaton" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)myApplication\.com$" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^myApplication/" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/myApplication/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: These are Apache rewrite rules. They won't work in IIS

Comment: Is it correct for apache?Any web.config rules  for the same work?Any Advice how to do it.Thnks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite to myApplicaton" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)myApplication\.com$" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^myApplication/" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/myApplication/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks Marco that you answered this but it did not work. There is 500 error.I don't know how to solve this .I have updated the question with what I tried.If you can do something so please help.Thanks.

Comment: The XML from your web.config you posted is invalid. I've updated my post to include the full XML you need to use as a start. Replace your web.config completely with mine from above. Mod_rewrite is the name of the Apache rewrite module. The module for IIS is called URLRewrite. If you don't have that installed yet, you can download it from [here](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite). You don't need to activate it or anything from the web.config, just adding the rewrite rule to web.config will active the URLRewrite module.